# Website is crashing

Tags: wordpress, error, permissions

I am using CiviCRM (5.69.4) install on Ubuntu 22.04 and wordpress but I am having the website crashed with the following error. Appreciate your help.

```
thrown in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php on line 230
[31-Jan-2024 16:16:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/sweetalert/sweetalert.civix.php on line 100
[31-Jan-2024 16:16:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/membershiprenewallink/membershiprenewallink.civix.php on line 100
[31-Jan-2024 16:16:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [unauthorized: Authorization failed
```

and

```
[PHP Notice] Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect at /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/sweetalert/sweetalert.civix.php:100
[PHP Notice] Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect at /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/membershiprenewallink/membershiprenewallink.civix.php:100
[PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:120
[PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:120
[PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:127
[PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:134
[PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:134

In Kernel.php line 230:
                    
  Authorization failed  
                    

setting:set [--in IN] [--out OUT] [--flat [FLAT]] [-T|--out=table] [-I|--out=list] [--columns COLUMNS] [-N|--dry-run] [--scope SCOPE] [--level LEVEL] [--hostname HOSTNAME] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER] [--] [<key=value>...]
```

Once I remove civicrm folder and install again I get

```
  [PHP Notice] Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect at /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/sweetalert/sweetalert.civix.php:100
  [PHP Notice] Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect at /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/membershiprenewallink/membershiprenewallink.civix.php:100
  [PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:120
  [PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:120
  [PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:127
  [PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:134
  [PHP Deprecation] str_contains(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated at /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/vars.php:134
  +--------+-----------+-------+----------+
  | scope  | key       | value | layer    |
  +--------+-----------+-------+----------+
  | domain | backtrace | 1     | explicit |
  +--------+-----------+-------+----------+
```

... and the website will be working again this is what is in Kernel.php:

```
  217   /**
  218    * Determine if the API request is allowed (under current policy)
  219    *
  220    * @param \Civi\API\Provider\ProviderInterface $apiProvider
  221    *   The API provider responsible for executing the request.
  222    * @param array $apiRequest
  223    *   The full description of the API request.
  224    * @throws Exception\UnauthorizedException
  225    */
  226   public function authorize($apiProvider, $apiRequest) {
  227     /** @var \Civi\API\Event\AuthorizeEvent $event */
  228     $event = $this->dispatcher->dispatch('civi.api.authorize', new AuthorizeEvent($apiProvider, $apiRequest, $this, \CRM_Core_Session::getLoggedInContactID() ?: 0));
  229     if (!$event->isAuthorized()) {
  230       throw new \Civi\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException("Authorization failed");
  231     }
  232   }
```

Comment: Just to note this is also discussed at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/zk38z776xjf8fxd1wacmrthf7w